# what happens when you install a library with npm and another library that has previous library as a dependency

Tags: javascript, npm

I have installed a library and now I want to install another library which is based on that one. I'm not sure which of the following will happen:

1. shared library will be installed once, second library will use this one for its purposes.
2. I'll have two copies of the same library and ultimately a larger bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have two copies of the same library and ultimately a larger bundle

Many libraries do peer dependencies for relatively big libraries (EG: react). So you can use a later version but npm will warn you there might be potential incompatibilities.

Comment: Thank you. I just read the peer dependency doc and I will add to that, there's `peerDependencies` entry in `package.json` and if the library does not have a dependency listed in there, it means it will make a different copy.